# Is it possible for @PropertySource to be used for properties with @Value?

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a new project and attempting to use Java config where I would previously use XML config. My app needs a `<property-placeholder>` like configuration. I have a configuration such as the following:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                    value = "classpath:app.config.properties"),
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                    value = "classpath:app.user.config.properties"),
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                    value = "file:///${app.config}")
})
public class TestConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Value("${prop1}")
    String prop1;

    @Bean
    public BasicData bd1() {
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("prop1"));
        System.out.println(prop1);
        return new BasicData("Test");
    }
```

`env.getProperty(String)` works as expected, though I though the `@Value` annotation may also have worked.

The configuration is getting instantiated through an MVC initialiser as follows:

```
public class AppInitializer
        extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            RootConfig.class,
            TestConfig.class,
            SecurityConfig.class
        };
    }
```

Previously I would have achieved this with XML config using the following:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:app.config.properties,classpath:app.user.config.properties,file:///${app.config}"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `@PropertySource` says the property sources are added to the `Environment`.

```
 * Annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding a
 * {@link org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource PropertySource} to Spring's
 * {@link org.springframework.core.env.Environment Environment}. To be used in
 * conjunction with @{@link Configuration} classes.
```

The replacement of placeholders is done by a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. This used to be `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, but since Spring 3.1 there's `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. I think it's a matter of adding a bean of this type to the context. Its documentation indicates it resolves placeholders against the `Environment`:

```
 * Specialization of {@link org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport
 * PlaceholderConfigurerSupport} that resolves ${...} placeholders within bean definition
 * property values and {@code @Value} annotations against the current Spring {@link
 * Environment} and its set of {@link PropertySources}.
```

Comment: Sorry for not seeing this! I think I missed it as i added my own answer at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the solution. I moved the `PropertySoure`(`s`) to the `RootConfig` which exposes a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                    value = "classpath:app.config.properties"),
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                    value = "classpath:app.user.config.properties"),
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                    value = "file:///${app.config}")
})
public class RootConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```